LsLidar Poll Timeout
I use LsLidar C16, but when I roslaunch, it says lslidar poll timeout(): UDP port. Can you help me how to fix this problem?
I did everything like turning on the firewall, changing the ip, eth0 going up, but still getting the lslidar poll time limit error. Please help me, Thank you.
Can you guys give me the details?

You need to provide more information; people can't help you with what's provided. What is the lidar's IP/subnet? What is your ros node running on? etc.
